# Setting background image in the bottom right corner but the bottom of the image is cut off

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a large logo image as a background image. I want to place it in the bottom right corner and remain there regardless of window size. I am using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>My Site</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



    <p class="centeredImage"><img src="image1.png"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body { 
    background-image: url("logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right bottom; 

}

.centeredImage
    {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }
```

This is placing the logo in the correct place however it is cut off slightly at the bottom of the window (red is the actual logo size):

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, I tried adding bottom padding to the body and it was no use. Could someone give me some pointers on what I might be doing wrong please?

Edit:

So I moved the logo into a div like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>My Site</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

   <div class="innerdiv"><img src="logo.png"></div>
   <p class="centeredImage"><img src="image1.png" width="375px" height="667px"></p>

</body>
</html>

.innerdiv {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 0px 0px;
}

.centeredImage
    {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    }
```

This is working correctly now and the logo isn't cut off however it is overlapping the image of the phone slightly, is there a way to force an image in the div to be displayed in the back?

Comment: can you please post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Adding this CSS should work:

```
.innerdiv img {
    z-index: 0;
}
.centeredImg {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Adding those codes should fix your issue.

Comment: Edited my answer a bit.

Comment: @KexAri inspect the backgroundcimage via: right-click -> inspect element

Comment: what am I looking for here?

Comment: Look for any paddings, margins which affect your image

Comment: Updated my answer according to the change in the question

Answer (score -1):

```
<p class="centeredImage"><img src="image1.png"></p>
```

First of all you have to mention the size of the image like try this one

```
<img src="image1.png" width="500px" height="100px">
```

Adjust the width and height of your choice.

Coming to logo.png try this one in CSS

```
background: url(logo.png);
background-size: 80px 60px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with that image. He is talking about logo.png

Comment: background: url(img_flwr.gif);
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: Ok Hassan Althaf change the CSS background-size

Comment: Tried that, still no change

Comment: Actually red is your logo then increase the logo size in CSS to background-size: 1000px 800px;